# array modifier not aligned

Tags: modifiers

I'm making a fort and I have made half and mirrored it. And I've made the first side view. Then I've added array with a count of 4 to complete the 4 sides like a square shape. I added an empty and rotate it by 90 degree. The problem is when I rotate, all sides do not match perfectly or are not aligned in square and some gap is created. The top 2 round circle when array should give 4 corners it's giving 8 corners.

**Before Mirror**
[image]

**1st Side view**
[image]

**After rotating 90 degree with empty**
[image]
What I'm doing wrong with the mesh alignment. Any suggestion or help is welcomed to complete the square.

Thanks

Comment: Your "45 degree corners" don't seem to be well geometrically aligned with the angle bisector

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos With adding mirror modifier image attach above

Comment: I see no reason... but using an object offset does not mean this object is at the center point... or here, you have not set the origin at the good place (not the center of the closed shape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experiments with array and mirror modifiers:

*Mirror and array* : your configuration more or less

[image]

After that, there is some guess to find the good position and this position will depend on both the object's origin and of the position of the 45° angle:

[image]

*Mirror and mirror*

And second way to do it is to place an empty at the middle of the 45° part (use snapping to do it), use it as mirror object and rotate it 45°.

[image]

Now add a second mirror, mirrored in X and Y, with a second empty as mirror object, and place this empty at the middle of the figure

[image]

Note that this last configuration (2 mirrors) does not depend on the object's origin location.

[Link to the blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2913/)

Comment: thanks for explanation but i do not want manually. I did little trick and got the solution. With the 1st image i have (Before mirror) i mirror and then array 4 times without applying all the modifier.

Comment: @ateks, sorry but I don't get what you mean in the comment here?